# Redirecting on exception from included jsp pages

Tags: jsp, exception

I have three jsp pages. main.jsp, header.jsp and footer.jsp.  Both header and footer jsps are included in main.jsp using `<jsp:include>`.  I am accessing main.jsp using url `domainname/main.jsp`.

Now i want to redirect to the error i.e.(error.jsp) when ever error occure in any of the included pages.

I tried using isErrorpage and errorpage attributes of page directives but in vain.
Any suggestion. Thanks in advance.

MORE INFO

```
    <jsp:include flush="true" page="/WEB-INF/general/DealFooter.jsp">
        <jsp:param value="<%=hotelId%>" name="PROPERTY_ID"/>
    </jsp:include>

    <jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/general/DealHeader.jsp">
        <jsp:param value="<%=hotelId%>" name="PROPERTY_ID"/>
    </jsp:include>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add following code to **main.jsp**

```
<%@page errorPage="Error.jsp" %>
```

Add Error.jsp in web-app
**Error.jsp**

```
<%@page isErrorPage="true" %>
<!-- print some message -->
<%= exception.toString() %>
```

No need to specify the  `<%@page errorPage="Error.jsp" %>` line in header and footer file just add it in main.jsp..

Comment: this dosn't redirect to error page but instead the error page get include in place of header and footer jsps.

Comment: can you paste your code in question.It may possible that you have problem in <%jsp:include />

Comment: It works fine when there is no exception in this included pages. I want to redirect the main page to this error page when error occures in any of this pages. The above scenario is just an example.

Comment: There is no need to do extra coding for that this code will redirect to Error.jsp when any Exception is generate in any of 3 jsp pages.

Comment: You must add that code in header.jsp it is sure after adding restart your server it may help you If your problem solve then accept & upvote answer.

Comment: I have dine this.  but this will only include error pages  to main jsp instead of header.